# How to pass details into <ion-item> received from Firebase with a click to another page on Ionic 3?

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, ionic3

I'm starting to develop my projects with Ionic and AngulaJS and I have a problem.

I get the Firebase data normally in an "ion-item", like (name, image, and details).

I need to show the details of the "uid" clicked on another page.

How do I do this?

Thank you very much if you help me.

This is my "ion-item"

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<ion-list *ngFor="let key of filteredusers">
  <ion-item>
    <ion-thumbnail item-start>
      <img src="{{key.photoURL}}">
    </ion-thumbnail>
    <h3>{{key.displayName}}</h3>
    <p>{{key.detalhes}}</p>
    <button ion-button round item-end>Ver Ofertas</button>
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

Showing the data received from the firebase:
[image: Showing the data received from the firebase]

Comment: What do you mean by page? If you're referring to another view, then you could pass a service around to exchange the data.

Comment: I already have an empty viewpage.
I want to move the details of the item clicked to it

Comment: are you using angularjs or angular?

Comment: Yes, I was able to show the value received from the other page on the console.
But how do I show this data on the page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply make a service for storing the UID and set it when user clicks on the list item in the `listing page` and get it in the `detail page`. I am supposing here that you have `uid` in the `filteredusers` array which can be accessed by `key.uid` and then you need to make an API call to firebase to get the data for that particular `uid`.

listing.component.html:

```
<ion-list *ngFor="let key of filteredusers">
    <ion-item>
        <ion-thumbnail item-start>
            <img src="{{key.photoURL}}">
        </ion-thumbnail>
        <h3>{{key.displayName}}</h3>
        <p>{{key.detalhes}}</p>
        <!-- REDIRECT USER TO DETAIL PAGE -->
        <button ion-button round item-end (click)="redirectToDetailPage(key.uid)">Ver Ofertas</button>
    </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

listing.component.ts:

```
...

redirectToDetailPage(uid) {
    // This is how we store it in service
    this.commonService.currentUID = uid;
    this.navCtrl.push(DetailPage);
}

...
```

detail.component.ts :

```
...

ionViewWillEnter() {
    this.http.post(this.firebaseURLYouKnow , {
        // pass uid of user clicked from listing page in API call
        uid: this.commonService.currentUID
    })
}

...
```

common.service.ts :

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable
export class commonService {
    public commonService: string;
}
```

You can learn more about services and how to use them [here](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt4)

Answer (score 0):

Hi in order to pass data from one view to another you can pass it using NavController [NavController](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/navigation/NavController/). 
Whenever you are pushing the view, pass second argument as object to be passed to the pushed view.

Try this:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
    <!--define a click event and pass the index of item clicked>
<ion-list *ngFor="let key of filteredusers; let i =index">
  <ion-item (click)="navigateTopage(index)">
    <ion-thumbnail item-start>
      <img src="{{key.photoURL}}">
    </ion-thumbnail>
    <h3>{{key.displayName}}</h3>
    <p>{{key.detalhes}}</p>
    <button ion-button round item-end>Ver Ofertas</button>
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

In your ts file

```
     //function in your ts class
     navigateTopage(index)
     {
      let filteredItem= this.filteredusers[index];
       //navigating to other page. navControl is type of NavController
      this.navContrl.push(<pageName>{
      'filteredItem': filteredItem
      })

     }
```

In your other details page you can get the pushed object by using:

```
   //key is same as we passed from previous page.
   this.navParams.get('filteredItem');
```

Happy to help :)